# how to install gentoo from usb to computer

Tags: system-installation, gentoo

Ive been recently planning starting for LFS (linux from scratch) and im now stuck installing gentoo

Comment: Welcome to the site. You already received an answer, but for the future, please keep in mind the "I'm not stuck installing gentoo" is far too unspecific for any contributor to understand what kind of problem you have, and hence, how they could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gentoo has a good installation guide: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64 and also guide for creating bootable USB: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LiveUSB/Guide

I'd recommend starting with these and if you have some specific problems, please ask more specific question, it's hard to help with "being stuck".

Also Gentoo is not a very "user friendly" distribution, if you have problems installing it, I'd suggest starting with Ubuntu, Linux Mint or Fedora -- getting more familiar with Linux with a "simpler" distribution first.

Comment: Actually gentoo has the all packages that i need